# autofill input field with value of another input field

Tags: jquery, input

I'm going crazy about this. 
I found a plain JavaScript solution for my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src=""> 

s1 = new String(catwebformform43575.EmailAddress.value)

function changeVal() {

    document.catwebformform43575.Username.value = catwebformform43575.EmailAddress.value;

}

</script>

<BR>
<BR>
<form name="catwebformform43575">
 <input type="text"id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" value="" onkeyup = "changeVal()">
 <input type="text" id="Username" name="Username" value="">
```

but I need a jQuery solution...Can anybody help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$("#EmailAddress").keyup(function(){
    $("#Username").val(this.value);
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxHQ5/)

Comment: @rahul, is there any other way to handle without keyup and key down?