# jQuery: autofill input values with mouse click not keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, mouseevent, mouse

I'm using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4932770/3108268

```
$("#EmailAddress").keyup(function(){
    $("#Username").val(this.value);
});
```

And it works fine when typing input values with a keyboard, it auto fills the selected field.

But it doesn't work when filling a field with a mouse click from calendar popup javascript plugin. The popup plugin gives the input classes `hasDatepicker date-popup-init`.

This is all inside Drupal 7, but I don't think it's relevant.

Here's an example, as you can see the time field is plain text and autofills below, because it is being filled with a keyboard while filling the date field with mouse click from calendar popup does not fill the field below it (but does if you force-type with keyboard).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `change` event;

```
$( "#EmailAddress" ).change(function() {
  $("#Username").val(this.value);
});
```